# how to get ID for several elements jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, web

I have a situation where I want to print labels on a form, and I'm using Label For to do this. I'd like to append the child tag's ID using jquery, but I'm not sure how.

so basically what I want to do is get the ID of several elements and append those IDs to my page. I want to keep my DOM and my jquery code as clean as possible. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Give them all the same class and $('.className') ? Its not very claer what you want/need.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand this is what you are trying to do.

This script will find all children of the label and give the label itself the children id.

Let me know if worked for you.

```
    <label >
         example 1
         <input type="text" id="id_1" />
    </label>
    <label >
         example 2
         <input type="text" id="id_2" />
    </label>
    <label >
         example 3
         <input type="text" id="id_3" />
    </label>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function(){
        $('body').find('label').each(function() {
            var idchild = $(this).children().attr('id');
            $(this).attr('id', idchild);
        });
    } );
    </script>
```